# What does CommonsPool2TargetSource do if you disable blockWhenExhausted?

Tags: spring, spring-aop, apache-commons-pool

The deprecated CommonPoolTargetSource had a set of behaviors you could define using [setWhenExhaustedActionName()](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/aop/target/CommonsPoolTargetSource.html#setWhenExhaustedActionName-java.lang.String-).  The CommonsPool2TargetSource and the CommonsPool2 [BaseGenericObjectPool](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-pool/apidocs/org/apache/commons/pool2/impl/BaseGenericObjectPool.html#getBlockWhenExhausted--) it wraps describe "getBlockWhenExhausted" as

> Returns whether to block when the borrowObject() method is invoked when the pool is exhausted

I figured that much out!  What does this do otherwise?

Does the Pool get expanded as in when you set CommonsPool to "WHEN_EXHAUSTED_GROW" or does it just throw an exception? What happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the documentation of [ObjectPool.borrowObject()](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-pool/apidocs/org/apache/commons/pool2/ObjectPool.html#borrowObject--) behavior when exhausted is implementation depended.

> The behaviour of this method when the pool has been exhausted is not strictly specified (although it may be specified by implementations).

The `GenericObjectPool` implementation supplied with CommonsPool2 will block if `getBlockWhenExhausted()` is true and immediately throw a `NoSuchElementException` otherwise. (as documented in [GenericObjectPoolborrowObject(long borrowMaxWaitMillis)](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-pool/apidocs/org/apache/commons/pool2/impl/GenericObjectPool.html#borrowObject-long-))

> If the pool is exhausted (no available idle instances and no capacity to create new ones), this method will either block (if BaseGenericObjectPool.getBlockWhenExhausted() is true) or throw a NoSuchElementException (if BaseGenericObjectPool.getBlockWhenExhausted() is false). The length of time that this method will block when BaseGenericObjectPool.getBlockWhenExhausted() is true is determined by the value passed in to the borrowMaxWaitMillis parameter.

A similar behavior to "WHEN_EXHAUSTED_GROW" is not available and is most likely reached by setting maxTotal to `-1` so the pool could not exhaust at all.